# What are my options for investing as a resident in Poland?

Tags: investing, savings, poland

I am intending to become resident in Poland in 2 years and would like to find ways of investing, eg: stocks and shares, tax free savings etc.

What are the options and how can I find them? (I don’t speak good enough Polish to search natively yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty brokerage houses and mutual fund platforms, however their materials are generally in Polish.

As for stock broker, this is one of the cheapest:
[DM BPS](https://dmbps.pl/)

And here you can check one of the fund platforms:
[KupFundusz](https://www.kupfundusz.pl)

As for tax free savings you have special pension-related accounts however I am not sure all tax residents are eligble:
[Pension accounts in Poland](https://www.enricotips.com/post/integrative-pension-plans-in-poland/)